# Unity3D object fill shader

Tags: unity, shaders, transparency

I've been researching this for a while, and had no luck yet. I figured I'd ask here to see if anyone had any good ideas.

Essentially what I want is a shader that can make only part of an object transparent based on a slider. Similar to fill effects on 2D sprites, the object would fill from the bottom up, when the slider was set to 0 the whole object would be transparent, when it was set to 50 just the bottom half would be visible, and when it was set to 100 the whole object would be visible.

I've tried various masking effects, but it would be best if I could build this in to existing shaders or have a separate mask. Is there perhaps a way to adjust the alpha on individual pixels used for the diffuse texture without incurring great performance loss?

Comment: I believe you could have a shader with two subshaders. One would have Queue Transparent and one would have Queue Geometry. With the transparent one draw the top bit based upon the world Y coordinate, with the solid one draw the bottom bit based upon the world Y coordinate.

Comment: How would drawing it based on the world Y coordinate accomplish what I was looking for? Wouldn't I have to move the object to get it to fill in, and then wouldn't it not fill in from the correct side?

Comment: I'm basing that on "the object would fill from the bottom up". I interpreted the bottom as low Y values. Basically you would draw the same object twice - once transparently and once opaquely. The trick is to not draw the whole object, only the bits you need.